# A book where one can learn psi powers from a book

Tags: story-identification, novel

Looking for a couple of book titles.

You can learn PSI powers from reading a book. There is a meeting place that is in a bubble in the heart of a star. They also use it to hide from other humans — I think it was a repressive society. The bubble is held open by psi powers.

Comment: Are these two books related? If not, then please edit one of them out of this post, and create a new post for the other.

Comment: I think it's one book. I have a vague recollection.